# iceccd outputs: Error: Address already in use

Tags: ip

I am having issues running iceccd.
When I run it I get the following error and I am not sure how to troubleshoot it.

```
$ sudo iceccd -vvvv 
[2031] 2021-01-05 11:22:27: ICECREAM daemon 1.3.1 starting up (nice level 5)  
[2031] 2021-01-05 11:22:27: 3 CPU(s) online on this server   
[2031] 2021-01-05 11:22:27: allowing up to 3 active jobs  
[2031] 2021-01-05 11:22:27: supported features: env_xz env_zstd  
[2031] 2021-01-05 11:22:27: not detaching  
[2031] 2021-01-05 11:22:27: entered process group  
[2031] 2021-01-05 11:22:27: ignoring localhost lo for broadcast  
[2031] 2021-01-05 11:22:27: broadcast enp0s3 13.0.2.255  
[2031] 2021-01-05 11:22:27: Netnames:  
[2031] 2021-01-05 11:22:27: starting to listen on all interfaces  
[2031] 2021-01-05 11:22:27: Failed to bind address to TCP listen socket(Error: Address already in use)  
[2031] 2021-01-05 11:22:29: Failed to bind address to TCP listen socket(Error: Address already in use)
```

Does any one know any flags that I can pass that will give me more insight on what is the issue?
Or maybe you have encountered something similar before and could offer some insight?
Clearly the IP is already used - but I am not sure what that actually means.
I have made no changes to icecc.conf.
Any other pointers what/where to look for (logs, config files etc) are greatly appreciated.
The IP is the IP of my machine (a VM):

```
$ ifconfig   
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500  
        inet 13.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 13.0.2.255  
        inet6 fe80::7018:a74c:8c50:c51e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>  
        ether 08:00:27:e4:98:c5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)  
        RX packets 34969  bytes 10208029 (10.2 MB)  
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0  
        TX packets 27138  bytes 2437506 (2.4 MB)  
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Disclaimer:
While I have used icecream as a developer in the past, this is my first attempt to configure one.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, really dumb on my part.
There was already automatically started instance of the daemon.